# Are unsigned integers standard in fortran?

Tags: integer, fortran, unsigned

In 2017, are unsigned integers in standard Fortran, or is it still a maybe not portable extension of some compilers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not standard and there is no active draft or similar activity in the committee to make them standard.

Comment: There was a proposal but it had very little support among the committee members. The bit functions were added to address most of what unsigned integers are used for. If I recall, the principal objections revolved around how they would interact arithmetically with signed types, plus a perception that they had limited uses in typical Fortran applications.

Comment: I recall there was a lot of discussion on comp.lang.fortran with people calling for them. But I look at the X3J3 or WG5 docs from time to time and I didn't see any work in progress. For me the important feature of unsigned integers is that the overflow is allowed. A lot of code assumes that silently about Fortran integers (pseudo random generators), but compilers are clever enough to find this and complain with some strict settings.

Comment: There was never any work-in-progress, as unsigned integers were not accepted as a work item by WG5. Each revision there are lots of proposals for new features, but most don't make the cut for acceptance. Only when WG5 approves a work item does the feature get looked at further.